# How can I bind custom click event handler to official Facebook Login button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Whenever I click official Facebook Login button from [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button) - browser blocks login popup window (even on this page). Can I bind custom click event handler to this button or initiate login process in the same window?

Answer (score 0):

You can block default behavior of a button with following code:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').on('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Do your logic here
});
```

In case you got the button in iframe:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
iframe.contentDocument.getElementById('myButton').on('click', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Do your logic here
    });
```

Comment: The problem is that Facebook Login button is inside iframe, so I cannot easily prevent an event on it